# Can't assign linux command output into a variable

Tags: bash

I've tried to write the following code in bash but I am not able to get the output to be echoed.

```
part1="blkid | grep -P 'CENTOS 7' | cut -c1-9"
echo "$part1"
```

Comment: Does that just echo the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
part1=$(blkid | grep -P 'CENTOS 7' | cut -c1-9)
echo "$part1"
```